# Receiving twice response when an HTTP request is made

Tags: ios7, xcode4.5

I am making a HTTP call to the server using the POST method.When the register button is clicked  am calling the service as given below

```
 NSURL * url=[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString         stringWithFormat:@"http://offers2win.com/api/v1/users?user[email]=%@&user[password]=%@&user[password_confirmation]=%@",username,password,confirmpassword]];
request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
connection=[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

And saving the responde data in the dictionary

```
 NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&err];
returnString  = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[returnString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] options:kNilOptions error:nil];
```

But the delegate is called twice

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
 NSLog(@"Recieved");
}
```

What could be the reason?And also it is taking a long time to get the response.

Answer (score 0):

This is not error. Apple has already told about this in NSURLConnectionDataDelegate Protocol Reference:

> In rare cases, for example in the case of an HTTP load where the
>   content type of the load data is multipart/x-mixed-replace, the
>   delegate will receive more than one connection:didReceiveResponse:
>   message. In the event this occurs, delegates should discard all data
>   previously delivered by connection:didReceiveData:, and should be
>   prepared to handle the, potentially different, MIME type reported by
>   the newly reported URL response.

Check Here : [NSURLConnectionDataDelegate Protocol Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLConnectionDataDelegate_protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSURLConnectionDataDelegate/connection%3adidReceiveResponse%3a)